# How to use OR with AND conditions for TypeORM repository

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I'm working on NestJS+TypeORM+SQL Server. I want to make a query like this,

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_orders 
WHERE branch_id = 1 
  AND (seller_id = 11 OR seller_id IS NULL);
```

My simple code is below. I have no idea how to put `seller_id IS NULL` condition like in the above query:

```
const result = await this.productRepository.find({
  where: { branch_id:1, seller_id:11},
  relations: ['seller']
});
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to tackle this would be to reconstruct the query as:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_orders 
WHERE (branch_id = 1 AND seller_id = 11) 
   OR (branch_id = 1 AND seller_id IS NULL);
```

To specify multiple conditions (OR operation), we can pass in an array of all the required condition instead of the condition object, and for specifying a NULL check, we can use the `IsNull()` operator function.

Reference: [Documentation](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/find-options#advanced-options)

```
import { IsNull } from 'typeorm';

// ...

const result = await this.productRepository.find({
    where: [
        { branch_id: 1, seller_id: 11 },
        { branch_id: 1, seller_id: IsNull() }
    ],
    relations: ['seller']
});
```